# Python List Iterate Trouble

Tags: python, windows

I'm having a very  hard time figuring out I'm doing wrong running my python script in Windows to get the expected result.

I have a directory with **list1.txt, list2.txt, list3.txt, list4.txt**, and **list5.txt**. Each list contains separate line strings that are unique such as list1.txt will have **item1, item2, item3, item4,** and **item5** each as values on separate lines. Then list2.txt will have item6-item10 on separate lines and so on.

What I need to do is to say, for each text file in this directory, list each value in list1 until done, then list each value in list2, then list3, and so on until you finish the last list.

Here is a link to the image of my results with notes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOPFD.png

The code I have it below but the results are not what I'm expecting and I'm having an extremly hard time determining what I'm doing wrong here.

```
def my_range(start, end, step):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start += step

for x in my_range(1, 5, 1):
   import os
   rootdir = os.getcwd()
   fis = rootdir + "\list\list" + str(x) + ".txt"
   files = open(fis,'rU')
   lines = files.readlines()
   print(lines)
   print(fis)
for line in lines:
        print("Item = " + line)
```

I need the results to read from every file in the lists.txt file and from every value in each file rather than just the last file. I think I'm not doing the for loop correctly nesting wise and I just cannot figure it out. I also tested with passing arguments to a function and defining a function to do this and I totally hosed up the script trying that.

Please anyone help me when you can with this problem I cannot figure out and just pulling my hair out of head.

Comment: Pro Tip: When possible, always include your output in your question, as links break over time.

Comment: Looks like it might just be an indentation problem to me. Try with the second last line indented

Comment: @SlickNutz unless I'm mistaken, posting a image or text does not require rep.

Comment: My guess (as mentioned in the Answer below) is the indentation problem, but I also called out below that it's much better to use Python's `with open()` capability as it releases file locks on completion/fail/crash/etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second `for` loop needs to be a sub-loop of the primary one. Also, do not `import os` each time you loop through, just do it once.  Your code should look like this:

```
def my_range(start, end, step):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start += step
import os
for x in my_range(1, 5, 1):
    rootdir = os.getcwd()
    fis = rootdir + "\list\list" + str(x) + ".txt"
    files = open(fis,'rU')
    lines = files.readlines()
    print(lines)
    print(fis)
    for line in lines:
        print("Item = " + line)
```

But, I would comment that you should instead use a `with open(fid,'rU') as f:` approach as that will release the file from being locked if the code errors out or crashes.  Then you could just do something like this:

```
def my_range(start, end, step):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start += step
import os
for x in my_range(1, 5, 1):
    rootdir = os.getcwd()
    fis = rootdir + "\list\list" + str(x) + ".txt"
    with open(fis,'rU') as files:
        print(fis)
        for line in files:
            print("Item = " + line)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your indentation is off:

```
for x in my_range(1, 5, 1):
   import os
   ...
for line in lines:             # this should be inside the loop
        print("Item = " + line)
```

However, you are going about this is a very roundabout way, I would recommend something like this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(starting_dir): # iterate over directory
  for f in files:                               # iterate over files
    with open(f) as in_file:                    # open file
      for line in in_file.readlines():          # iterate over lines
        print line                              # print each line (or do something else)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.path.join` to create path to a file. I've made some improvement's I'll talk about below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
rootdir = os.getcwd()

for x in range(1, 4):
   filename = 'list' + str(x) + '.txt'
   fis = os.path.join(rootdir, 'list', filename)
   files = open(fis,'rU')
   lines = files.readlines()
   print(lines)
   print(fis)
for line in lines:
        print("Item = " + line)
```

I also don't see any point in making own iterable. Why don't you simply use `range(1, 5)` at the beginning? Next: make names descriptive. Now it may not seem important, but after a week you'll be asking yourself "What the hell did I mean by this fis". Any IDE will make working with long names easier and, believe me, writing `data_file_name` or something akin is more pleasant than `dfs` etc. Don't import anything in a loop. It reduces efficiency. Also `rootdir` variable can be declared once.

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through all your files but then only displaying the results of the last file. You need to indent the second for loop:

```
for x in my_range(1, 5, 1):
    import os
    rootdir = os.getcwd()
    fis = rootdir + "\list\list" + str(x) + ".txt"
    files = open(fis,'rU')
    lines = files.readlines()
    print(lines)
    print(fis)
    for line in lines: #INDENT LIKE SO
        print("Item = " + line)
```

Comment: Your code syntax is incorrect, please fix as it will not work.